# Which site supply movie information with API for free?

Tags: api, imdb

I need:

- movie title
- director
- cast
- story

I cannot use IMDB.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.filmcrave.com/api.php

any good?

Comment: Yeah I should have gone further and said Film Crave looks like it's the best one for the OP's needs.

Answer (score 3):

[TMDb](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1) looks like a very good and very open choice. That's what I'm going to go with for one of my future projects :)

Answer (score 2):

Try these: http://www.programmableweb.com/apitag/?q=movie